# Cmake - Relocation error at runtime when running in server

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux, relocation

I started with C and C++ a few days ago and I'm losing my mind with this problem. I wrote and compiled a program in C++ using cmake in a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL, Ubuntu). The program opens a CSV file, does some filtering and streams out the result as a JSON string. I need to process very fast some csv files in my website, which is hosted by Bluehost, so I thought I could make something in C++ and run it from php with the `exec()` function. The server uses Linux and php for the backend.

- Before going deeper into C++ I compiled a simple program that prints "Hello world!" using `printf()` and tested it with `exec()` in the server. It worked fine.
- Then I spent some time on C++ and got an executable that works perfectly when I run it in my own device (WSL).
- Finally I upload to the server the executable and all the libraries (listed with `ldd`), except `linux-vdso.so.1`, and try to run the program. All the files are in the same directory since I can't access the libs of the server. It throws the following error:

```
./lib/esp_query: relocation error: /lib/libpthread.so.0: symbol __tunable_get_val, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference"
```

Both `libpthread.so.0` and `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` are libraries that the command `ldd` listed and I uploaded to the server. Before that, I tried to run a simple "Hello world!" example with `printf` in the server and it worked fine, so I know I can run this kind of files in the server and the c++ code isn't the problem since it worked fine in my device.

I think there's a problem with the libraries, but I'm unable to find where the problem is and a way to fix it. This is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
SET(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH $ORIGIN)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(esp_query)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(DataFrame REQUIRED CONFIG)

add_executable(esp_query esp_query.cc)

target_link_libraries(esp_query PRIVATE DataFrame Threads::Threads)
target_compile_options(esp_query
    PRIVATE $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/bigobj>
)
```

I've been a couple of days looking for a fix, but I didn't find anything like that in Google or in other similar questions in this site. Can you help me point out where's the error and how can I fix it, please?

**EDIT:** solved. The problem was a bit more complex, but the solution was the same that fabian and Someprogrammerdude pointed in their comments and I think this make be helpful for somebody in the future.

- I downloaded and installed a CentOS 7 linux distro in order to make the compilation in an OS with similar libraries (since the web server uses Cloudlinux 6.10 and both Cloudlinux 6.10 and CentOS 6 gave me weird errors when trying to install).
- I was using the C++ DataFrame package by hosseinmoein. This package requires C++ 11 standards that are not supported by the Cent OS 7 and gcc/g++ base libraries (given the version of the compiler avalaible at yum). I guess that it is very unlikely that the admins of Bluehost web servers installed a newer version of the compiler, so I wanted to keep it in that version too, to avoid more problems. This forced me to discard the DataFrame package option and make another program that complies with C++ 98 standards. This worked like a charm.

Comment: My guess is that you need to rebuild your application on the real target.

Comment: Sounds like the library version you link agains on the WSL is incompatible with the pthread lib available on the target system. You may need to install the proper compiler for the target system and do a crosscompilation or at least copy the relevant system libs from the server and specify a sysroot for use by your compiler using [`CMAKE_SYSROOT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html). Note that cross compilation in the WSL seems to work fine (using a toolchain targeting `aarch64` at work), but I don't have any experience with the default gcc in the WSL...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude do mean to build the application in the web server or to make a new installation of WSL with the same linux distro and version the web server is using and build the app there? In fact, if I compile on a WSL with the same distro and version as the target system the application should work because both systems would have the same libraries, right?